# How does AddAttributeBefore work in the Resharper API?

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-6.1, resharper-plugins

In the Resharper API, `JetBrains.Resharper.Psi.Csharp.Tree.AddAttributeBefore` takes an `IAttribute param`, and an `IAttribute anchor`. How are these arguments different, and how can  they be constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a peek at the [working with XML document](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/exportword?pageId=38963614) inside it shows use of the `AddAttributeBefore` call the first is the attribute you wish to insert. The second one is a attribute that already exists that you wish to insert before. If the second attribute is `NULL` the new attribute is inserted after the last attribute.

Comment: What if I want to convert a string into a simple attribute in front of a C♯ method, *e.g.* `[Obsolete]`?

Comment: @Matthew Piziak Try using myClass.AddAttributeBefore(CSharpElementFactory.GetInstance(myClass.GetPsiModule()).CreateTypeMemberDeclaration("["+yourAttribute+"] void Aaa() {}").Attributes[0], null). Didn't test it, though.

Answer (score 2):

basically, the `param` is what you want to add, and `anchor` is the element before which you want to add something. Keep in mind that you can, in most cases, have `anchor == null`, which would cause the element to be added last.